# Invalid ExtensionInterface for nonexistent class Interface with setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2

I started getting this error running `bin/magento setup:di:compile`:

> Invalid ExtensionInterface for nonexistent class Interface in file /bitnami/magento/htdocs/app/code/Magento/TestModuleExtensionAttributes/Api/Data/FakeExtensibleTwoInterface.php

Deleting the `generated/` and `var/` folders did not help, nor did emptying the cache and re-indexing. Has anyone encountered a problem like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that you try to run the test on this installation. And test copy test modules in app/code folder and do not remove it.

Please delete app/code/Magento/Test* modules manually and re run compilation

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick

Comment: For further information why the modules have been generated and which other issues come with them see https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12696

Answer (score 6):

I found that specifying `Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesInterface` and the methods `getExtensionAttributes` & `setExtensionAttributes` in my Repository class:

```
namespace MY\MODULE\Api\Data;

use Magento\Framework\{
    Api\ExtensibleDataInterface,
    Api\ExtensionAttributesInterface,
    Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
};

/** @api */
interface MyModelInterface extends ExtensibleDataInterface
{
   ......

   /** @return ExtensionAttributesInterface */
   public function getExtensionAttributes(): ExtensionAttributesInterface;

   /** 
    * @param ExtensionAttributesInterface 
    * @return CatalogProductIndexPriceLogModelInterface
    */
   public function setExtensionAttributes(ExtensionAttributesInterface $extensionAttributes): CatalogProductIndexPriceLogModelInterface;
```

Was causing:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Interception cache generation... 6/7 [========================>---]  85% 36 secs 476.0 MiBErrors during configuration scanning:
    ExtensionAttributesInterface
        Invalid ExtensionInterface for nonexistent class ExtensionAInterface in file /home/www/projects/magento2/the-block-shop/src/app/code/Convert/MonitorIndexers/Api/Data/CatalogProductIndexPriceLogModelInterface.php
Total Errors Count: 1
```

Removing these from the my interface but keeping them in my concrete class then running:

```
rm -rf generated/ && php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Worked.

Comment: you just saved me from hours of hair-pulling :)

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I want to do here! :)

Comment: @ChrisRogers any clue why this was not working

Comment: Not too sure why but, perhaps it has something to do with either: Not formatting phpdoc correctly (/** @api */) or that I/we might be specifying strict type return values! Magento ay!!

Answer (score 2):

Full path need to be set. See my case:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
/**
 * Retrieve existing extension attributes object or create a new one.
 *
 * @return \YourVendor\YourModule\Api\Data\YourModelExtensionInterface|null
 */
  public function getExtensionAttributes();

/**
 * Set an extension attributes object.
 *
 * @param \YourVendor\YourModule\Api\Data\YourModelExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes
 * @return $this
 */
  public function setExtensionAttributes(
    \YourVendor\YourModule\Api\Data\YourModelExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes
  ): self;
```

for me it worked with full path